# JSFL - How to change the font of a text field?

Tags: flash, jsfl

Im trying to set the font (face) of a textfield.

Ive tried both :

```
textElement.setTextAttr("face", replacementFont);
textElement.setTextAttr.face = replacementFont;
```

Where replacementFont is the text name of the desired font.

This doesnt work - am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually and then looking at the history panel and see what it did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up an issue with the way I was loading in my replacement fonts.

I had made a csv file containing the font mapping. And the font names were containing a new line character.

I parsed out the new line character. Interestingly enough the new line character was required to compare and match the font map.

Answer (score 2):

'textElement.setTextAttr("face", replacementFont);' works for me.
Probably the font you are trying to replace with, is not installed.
You could try this:

```
textElement.setTextAttr('face', replacementFont);
if (textElement.getTextAttr('face') != replacementFont)
{
    fl.trace("Font '" + replacementFont + "' is not available!\nTry a different font!");
}
```