# how to change font face to an imported font in jsfl

Tags: flash, jsfl

i'm writing a jsfl to change all textfields to an imported font, and i know how to change font face of textfield from this question [JSFL - How to change the font of a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328448/jsfl-how-to-change-the-font-of-a-text-field)

the problem is that, i can change the font into an installed font, but i can not change it into an imported font named `$NormalFont`,here are some screen shot which may make me understood.
[image]

below is the property of `$NormalFont`
[image]

so in my code, i call the function like this:

```
textElement.setTextAttr("face", "$NormalFont");
```

nothing changed. but i do can manually change the text font like below:
[image]

and i notice that here the name of the font is `$NormalFont*`,with a star.
so i call the function like this:

```
textElement.setTextAttr("face", "$NormalFont*");
```

nothing changed again.

anyone can help me? because i have over 100 fla files to change...

Answer (score 0):

`face` here is Font family, which is `Microsoft YaHei`, not `$NormalFont`.

`$NormalFont` is the `name` property of the `fontItem` that you embed in Library.

*(About the asterisk, I think it's there just to remind that it's an embedded font and nothing more. That's why in Library you don't see it on the `fontItem`, because you already know that it's an embedded font.)*

For instance, if the font you embed is the first item in Library's item array:

```
fl.trace(document.library.items[0].font);//Microsoft YaHei  (1)
fl.trace(document.library.items[0].name);//$NormalFont
```

So you can use `Microsoft YaHei` or `微软雅黑`:

```
textElement.setTextAttr("face", "Microsoft YaHei");
textElement.setTextAttr("face", "微软雅黑");
```

If you must use a custom name like `$NormalFont`, first find the `item` with the name `$NormalFont` in Library, then get the `font` attribute of it, then set it as `face` for the textfields.

```
var myFontItem;
var itemArray = document.library.items;
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
    if (itemArray[i].name == '$NormalFont') {
        myFontItem = itemArray[i];
    }
}

textElement.setTextAttr("face", myFontItem.font);
```

(1) There's a problem with this, is that JSFL can't get/set font styles of a `fontItem` in Library (or I don't know how, even AS3 has problems when it comes to fonts). In case of simple bold/italic fonts like YaHei Bold, just set it like this:

```
textElement.setTextAttr("bold", true);
```

But if you want to use more styles like black condensed etc, your best bet is to directly edit the font file data to make a new custom font and install it, so that the font name in Flash IDE is unique, then use that name. I had to do that once.

Comment: "If you must use a custom name like $NormalFont",i do what you told me to do.get the `font` attribute of the `item` then set it as `face` for the textfields. but the result is no difference with `textElement.setTextAttr("face", "Microsoft YaHei");` no custom name setted

Comment: sorry for my delay response because i just had a holiday outside and forgot about this thing

Comment: (never mind the delay :-)
Was it a TLFTextField? (or ASElement in JSFL, it's one of those undocumented-then-deprecated things)

Comment: no, it is not a TLFTextField. but it is an ASElement in JSFL, because i traverse all elements in fla file, and when its `elementType` property is `text`, then i would want to change its font name to a custome name like `$NormalFont`

Comment: Does `textElement.setTextAttr("face", "Microsoft YaHei");` or `textElement.setTextAttr("face", "微软雅黑");` work when the font isn't imported?

Comment: As in my first reply, setTextAttr doesn't work with a custom name.
Do it like this: (see my first reply up there for formatting)

`var myFontItem;
var itemArray = document.library.items;
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
 if (itemArray[i].name == '$NormalFont') {
  myFontItem = itemArray[i];
 }
}
textElement.setTextAttr("face", myFontItem.font);`